# My Toggle Button to hide rows causes my VBA code cells to #VALUE error

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I've just discovered Toggle Buttons and have input a number to hide and unhide various sections of my sheet when they're not in use.

Within each hidden section I'm using a VBA code to sum bold and sum italics, and at the bottom of the page have an equation to add those cells together to give me the total for the whole sheet.

When I hide a section the VBA code to sum bold/italic gives a #VALUE error, also giving the additions cell at the bottom the same. If I click on the errored sum bold/italic cell's equation and press enter it goes back to normal, but obviously if the cell is hidden I'm unable to do this.

Manually hiding the cells doesn't cause the same issue, only using the button. Is there something I can add in to stop this from happening?

I know I can change my additions cell to use the VBA code for each section, but if there's a loop around to just fix the error from coming up that would be easier.

For reference this is my button code format:

```
Private Sub Hide1_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "7:14"
If Hide1.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = False
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

And this is my sum bold format

```
Function SumBold(WorkRng As Range)
'Update 20220516
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xSum As Double
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Font.Bold Then
        xSum = xSum + Rng.Value
    End If
Next
SumBold = xSum
End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have a button named Hide1.  The Hide1.Value  is a cell named Hide1 ?? Button don't have a value property...

Comment: Just a comment but using bold font as a filter is probably a bad practice. It would be better to have a second column to store data about included or excluded values, and populate this value with yes/no or true/false or include/exclude or 0/1 or some such marker. Then your sum function is a simple conditional formula and you get the benefits of built-in filtering and better, faster, more maintainable structure (and vba may not be needed at all).

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ: Buttons don't, but ToggleButtons have a value.

Comment: @topsail Yeah it's not something I would do if it was purely for data but it's to produce a customer friendly report for hires of costumes where the bold numbers are ones that are charged two different rates of laundry (bold and italics). The variety of types of outfit and item are a little endless and need to be able to be fully customisable so this has worked pretty well for this purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some back and forth with ChatGPT and found a solution to the problem.
The range was only numeric cells so that wasn't the issue, and it didn't pose a problem when manually hiding cells so the toggle button was the issue.

This amendment to the toggle buttons fixed it.

```html
Private Sub Hide1_Click()
    Dim xAddress As String
    xAddress = "7:14"
    
    If Hide1.Value Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Disable screen updating
    
    ' Recalculate formulas
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Enable screen updating
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont think you ask ChatGPT, I dont think that the code in Private Sub Hide1_Click() works at all. The Hide1_Click means that there is a button with name Hide1. The Typename(Hide1) gives "CommandButton" even if you have a named cell with same name. So the Value property is incorrect!!  Why?

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ `Typename(Hide1)` will give `ToggleButton`.

Comment: Apologies for my point, obviously reading the question too quickly will be to blame!

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in some values, which are not numeric. The corrected Function below will reveal the non-numeric values to you in the Immediate window

```vb
Option Explicit

Function SumBold(WorkRng As Range) As Double
   ' Update 20220516
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim xSum As Double
   For Each Rng In WorkRng
      If Rng.Font.Bold Then
         If IsNumeric(Rng.Value2) Then
            xSum = xSum + Rng.value
         Else
            Debug.Print "Cell " & Rng.Address(0, 0) & " is not numeric!"
         End If
      End If
   Next
   SumBold = xSum
End Function
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully: The calculation function works (sometimes), so the issue is *not* having non-numeric values.

Comment: This code still produces the #VALUE error when the `Rows.Hidden` property is accessed in VBA. The problem is not in the values. The problem seems to be that the function cannot determine the `Rng.Font.Bold` property after the `Rows.Hidden` property has been accessed. Stepping through the formula, it fails at the `If Rng.Font.Bold Then` line.